# S3 File Uploading Issue with public read access

Tags: php, amazon-s3

When I uploading images on S3 with private access its work fine. But when same file want to upload with public-read access, it gives me error

```
Warning: S3::putObject(): [AccessDenied] Access Denied in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\kitedog\libs\s3\S3.php on line 355
```